# Is server side validation required, when data is posted through ajax?

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-validate, validation

In my project, I am storing FORM data by POSTING it to one php file. I am sending data through ajax on buttonclick and i am doing client side validation, so anyways i can not do database insertion without javascript, then do i need server side validation??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. The environment the client runs in is entirely outside your control and you should consider it hostile and potentially compromised.

Your question also contains a false assumption. You say, "when data is posted through ajax". But how do you know that? When you see some data comes to your server over the Internet, you have absolutely no way to tell what software that data is coming from. That's how *you* intend it to be posted, but unless you control every machine on the network, that's just how you intended it to happen. Obviously, an attacker (or even an experimenter) won't honor your wishes.

Comment: but if javascript is diabled , it is not possible to insert data

Comment: @AmitParmar: You can't assume anything about what computers and software do that is outside your control. Someone can submit anything they want to your server. You *must* validate everything in the server and consider everything outside your control potentially hostile. (SQL injection attacks are the most obvious such attack.)